# Azure Worker Roles, Most optimal method to aggregate data in memory?

Tags: multithreading, azure, aggregate, azure-storage-queues

I have these X number of worker roles that will process the Azure Queues using multiple threads. The data that flows in these queues is rather simple (for this Client_ID we have action A, B or C, one action per transaction) but there will be a lot of it, over 5000 transactions every second. Now I need to aggregate these in a format that shows Client_ID, 43 transactions of type A, 20 for B, and 11 for C. Basically sum them up. But the GetMessages on the queue can only retrieve 32 messages from the queue.

My question is - should I keep retrieving 32 at the time until i have say a 1000, then run through them and sum them up? Or hold totals in a list, queue, or cache?

What would you recommend for the most optimal aggregator mechanism for my scenario, knowing that there might be 10 worker roles with 5 threads getting messages from these queues at all times?

Comment: I have done this before. What is the level of accuracy you need here - is it 100% or can you tolerate some slippage (say in the case, an instance goes down).

Comment: @Lucifure - this is not critical data so there is some room to play with. Awaiting your suggestion :)

Comment: If accuracy is not critical, knightpfhor's response is on the money. Read and delete messages as fast and you can, (32 at a time maybe on multiple threads), hold summarized data in memory and write it out periodically.

Answer (score 0):

To start with I think it would be good to read this [always popular article](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/architecting-scalable-counters-with-windows-azure) and related [Cloud Cover Episode](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure) about building scalable counters in Azure.

In short what it says is that each worker role keeps a thread safe counter (in your case for each client and message type).  The threads update those counters as they process each message.  A background thread then periodically writes that values to your underlying storage.